# An IF steatment on a control source

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, if-statement

Is there a way to include an if statement on this control source?

=DCount("*","[SOBRANTES]","[ID]=" & [Forms]![formedita]![ID])

Something like 
=if not new.record DCount("*","[SOBRANTES]","[ID]=" & [Forms]![formedita]![ID])

Comment: Where is the expression, on a form or report? In a subreport? Have you discovered the IIF function?

Comment: The expression is a text box source inside a form that contains a subform. I´ll check the iif function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `NewRecord` property via the forms' `Form` property (I know that sounds strange). It will either be True or False. You can use this value as the IIf function's test condition.

```
=IIf([Forms]![formedita].Form.NewRecord,"New",
    DCount("*","[SOBRANTES]","[ID]=" & [Forms]![formedita]![ID]))
```

If the expression is in a subform then you need to reference the `Parent` object, something like `[Forms]![formedita].Form.Parent.Form.NewRecord` or `[Forms]![formedita].Parent.Form.NewRecord`.

But you can simplify this by just referencing `Forms!parent_form_name` in the above IIf formula.

Comment: The expression is in the main form. Perfect! Really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: It really works very very well. Especially displaying New when new Record